# How do i make shape key driver only show up when it rotates backwards in the x axis

Tags: modifiers, drivers, shape-keys, graph-editor, axis

I created a corrective shape key for a quadruped leg, for when i move it backwards. I want the shape key only to appear when the leg rotates backwards in the X axis, but it shows when i rotate the leg frontwards too. i tried limits and restrict frame range, but i didn't get any results.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate the Bone.046, set a copy rotation of the original in local space, followed by a limit rotation constraint, and use it as source for the driver.

As it is a copy it will inherit every parenting options.

Limit rotation must be last in the stack.

Comment: I tried this, and doesn't work. I duplicated the bone and set the copy rotation and limit rotation with the right values, but the bone continues to rotate everyhere that the bone 046 rotates, the bone should stop rotating at some point, but it doesn't. Then i tried to add copy location and limit location, but the bone follow the orginal one everywhere, the limits doesn't work. I even tried unparenting the bone and creating a bone from another armature to see if works, but it doesn't.

Comment: Set the limit rot constraint to local space.

Comment: I fixed the copy rotation by making the bone not parent, i didn't know why it wasn't working when i first tried. Now. Now i did this with the copy location and limit location, but that does'nt work with local space, just with world space, and now i'm stuck and another problem, when i move the leg foward with this location constraint, the number of the corrective shapekey goes to zero, when it is in rest pose, it goes to 1.000, tried changing settings with the generator modifier, it gets worst, guess i'll have to create another post for that...